# Jquery, Div in view / link hover, fixed menu "pop out"

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the following code for a fixed side menu that pops out on hover. Code found online, and easily integrated..

CSS:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="home"><a class="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="museum"><a class="museum" href="#museum">Museum</a></li>
        <li class="collection"><a class="collection" href="#collection">Collection</a></li>
        <li class="timeline"><a class="timeline" href="#timeline">Timeline</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a class="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
// link hover
$(function() {
    $('.nav a').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-140px'},200);
    $('.nav > li').hover(
        function () {
            $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-45px'},200);
        },
        function () {
            $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-140px'},200);
        }
    );
});
```

And I use the PlusAnchor script to scroll the page to the right divs:

```
// Page Scroll
$('body').plusAnchor({
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    speed:  1000,
    offsetTop: -60
});
```

Now I need to modify the code, but I don't know how being new to Jquery. I need for the menu items to remain "popped out" after a user clicks, or to "pop out" as the user scrolls and the div in question comes in to view.

How can I achieve this? Is there a script I can adopt?

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/AG3tg/

Comment: can you just provide a fiddle for it?

Comment: ok.. I added a JSFiddle

Comment: Create a class called `.active` or something.  Create the css for `.active`, then apply a click event on the `li`. Something like: `$('.nav li').click(function(){ $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you need to record when the element is clicked, and handle it accordingly. Update your jQuery code as follows:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    // link hover
    $('.nav a').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-140px'},200);
    $('.nav > li').hover(
        function () {
            $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-45px'},200);
        },
        function () {
            if(!$(this).data('shown'))
            {
                $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-140px'},200);
            }
        }
    ).click(function() {  
        $('.nav > li').data('shown', false);
        $(this).data('shown', true);
        $('.nav > li a').not(':eq('+$(this).index()+')').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-140px'},200);
    });

    // plus anchor
    $('document').plusAnchor({
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        speed:  1000,
        offsetTop: -60
    });
})
```

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AG3tg/2/)

Comment: That is quiet beautiful. Thank you. Only as you scroll, the div in focus should change the menu so that the correct item is out. I think jquery.focus comes in handy here. Let me try this one on my own. Thanks again.

Comment: `focus()` is used when an element gains focus (like clicking a link, or focusing on a text input). You'll need to put together some form of scrollspy for the feature that you described.